# Using pdfcrop within epstopdf?

Tags: epstopdf, pdfcrop

Currently, my epstopdf is not able to convert eps to pdf correctly due to the **boundingbox (atend) bug** that the epstopdf does not support. However, I intend to use pdfcrop on the generated pdf file and that usually fix the white space problem. However, I have to manually fix every generated file. Is there a way to automate this in latex? For example, **automatically calling pdfcrop immediately after epstopdf**. I tried using DeclareGraphicsRule in epstopdf but it wasn't working.

Please advise. Thanks a lot ! :)

Comment: Which bug? `atend` is supported by `epstopdf`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following adds an option `crop` to `graphicx`/`\includegraphics`. If enabled, it 
adds `pdfcrop` to the conversion of `.eps` to `.pdf`.

Because `pdfcrop` is not added to the restricted shell escape command list, full
shell escape is needed: `--shell-escape` (TeX Live) or `--enable-write18` (MiKTeX).

If the file is converted and uptodate, changing the option `crop` does not have an effect.
Also the option does not affect other image files.

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}

\makeatletter
\newif\ifGin@pdfcrop
\Gin@pdfcroptrue
\define@key{Gin}{crop}[true]{%
  \csname Gin@pdfcrop#1\endcsname
}
\epstopdfDeclareGraphicsRule{.eps}{pdf}{.pdf}{%
  epstopdf --outfile=%
  \ifGin@pdfcrop
    tmp-image.pdf #1 &&
    pdfcrop tmp-image.pdf \OutputFile
  \else
    \OutputFile\space#1%
  \fi
}
\makeatother
```

Example usages:

```
\includegraphics{foo1}
\includegraphics[crop]{foo2}
\includegraphics[crop=false]{foo3}
\setkeys{Gin}{crop}
\setkeys{Gin}{crop=false}
```

Comment: oh wow.. this works beautifully! Thanks so much.. appreciate it :) :)