# How to run pdfcrop when using \includegraphics with a PDF?

Tags: graphics, pdf, pdfcrop

This question is similar to [that one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/81765/using-pdfcrop-within-epstopdf), but I'd like to execute pdfcrop when including a PDF.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When the shell escape feature (`--shell-escape` or `--enable-write18` (MiKTeX)) is enabled, the conversion can be called via `\immediate\write18{...}`:

```
\immediate\write18{pdfcrop image.pdf}%
\includegraphics{image-crop}
```

The conversion can be limited to the cases, where the cropped image file not yet exists:

```
\IfFileExists{image-crop.pdf}{}{\immediate\write18{pdfcrop image.pdf}}%
\includegraphics{image-crop}
```

Comment: You might mention the `shellesc` package, which will be particularly handy when LuaTeX 0.90 will be included in TeX Live 2016 and won't support `\write18`.

Answer (score 1):

Based on Heiko Oberdiek's answer I wrote a command to crop all included PDFs

```
\usepackage{xstring}
\let\oldincludegraphics\includegraphics
\renewcommand{\includegraphics}[2][width=\textwidth]{%
    \immediate\write18{pdfcrop #2}%
    \StrSubstitute{#2}{.pdf}{-crop.pdf}[\temp]%
    \oldincludegraphics[#1]{\temp}%
    }
```

Issues:

- it doesn't check if the graphic is a PDF
- it should be optional

Comment: this is missing `%` at ends of lines so will add three inter-word spaces before the image, and one after.