# Unwanted white space when compiling to pdf from eps

Tags: pdftex, margins, epstopdf

A journal requires submission of figures in .eps format, so I need to be able to compile using an eps image "on the fly". Here is a MWE which uses an eps graphics file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
  \begin{figure}[t]
    \centering
    \caption{too much white space!}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{fdr80}
  \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The [eps image](http://www.filedropper.com/fdr80) has minimal margins (by fixing its BoundingBox), but the [converted pdf image](http://www.filedropper.com/fdr80-eps-converted-to) has too much white space on top (I think latex does the conversion automatically, I don't call epstopdf but I can see it being used in the log). How do I get rid of the white space? I've already tried the answer at [Using pdfcrop within epstopdf?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/81765/using-pdfcrop-within-epstopdf) and it doesn't work: I get an error saying that it can't find the pdf file. (so epstopdf called by pdflatex is probably failing there).

EDIT: Some more information is in order. I produced the eps figure using R. More importantly, I used the R package "extrafont" to embed a Computer Modern font into the eps. I believe this embedding is causing the problem. I just tried to use a simple eps (no embedding of fonts) and tex converts it to a pdf with the correct borders, no additional white space on top.

Comment: impossible to say much given this amount of information, but if you put `\frame{\includegraphics....}` is the extra space inside or outside the box drawn be `\frame` ?

Answer (score 2):

Upon inspecting the eps file (in a text editor), I saw that there were two lines starting with `%%HiResBoundingBox`. Deleting the wrong one fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with a .eps file exported from Matlab, which ended up with unwanted margins on the top and right of the image when converted to .pdf. I thought that I would add an answer here since I came to this question through a web search.

In my case, the .eps file had `PageBoundingBox` and `BoundingBox` lines set as follows:

```
%%Page: 1 1
%%PageBoundingBox: 0 0 641 29
...
%%Trailer
%%BoundingBox: 0 0 653 35
%%Pages: 1
%%EOF
```

In this case, the two were different, and copying the values from `PageBoundingBox` to `BoundingBox` removed the unwanted margins.